# Sending email with attachment using scala and Liftweb

Tags: scala, lift

This is the first time i am integrating Email service with liftweb

I want to **send Email with attachments(Like:- Documents,Images,Pdfs)**
my code looking like below

```
       case class CSVFile(bytes: Array[Byte],filename: String = "file.csv",
                     mime: String = "text/csv; charset=utf8; header=present" )

       val attach = CSVFile(fileupload.mkString.getBytes("utf8"))

       val body = <p>Please research the enclosed.</p>

       val msg = XHTMLPlusImages(body,
                  PlusImageHolder(attach.filename, attach.mime, attach.bytes)) 

      Mailer.sendMail(
      From("vyz@gmail.com"),
      Subject(subject(0)),
      To(to(0)),
     )
```

this code is taken from LiftCookbook its not working like my requirement
its working but only the Attached file name is coming(file.csv) no data in it(i uploaded this file (gsy.docx))

Best Regards
GSY

Comment: > "its not working like my requirement" - how exactly doesn't it work? Does it compile? Does it send a message (even without an attachment)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what type `fileupload` is, but assuming it is of type `net.liftweb.http. FileParamHolder` then the issue is that you can't just call `mkString` and expect it to have any data since there is no data in the object, just a `fileStream` method for retrieving it (either from disk or memory).

The easiest to accomplish what you want would be to use a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and copy the data to it. I haven't tested it, but the code below should solve your issue. For brevity, it uses [Apache IO Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to copy the streams, but you could just as easily do it natively.

```
val data = {
  val os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  IOUtils.copy(fileupload.fileStream, os)
  os.toByteArray
}

val attach = CSVFile(data)
```

BTW, you say you are uploading a Word (DOCX) file and expecting it to automatically be CSV when the extension is changed? You will just get a DOCX file with a `csv` extension unless you actually do some conversion.

Comment: I am glad to help. If that solved your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to let others know that the issue is resolved.